# Center align floated div inside it's floated container

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a floated container with multiple child floated divs.

I want to center align (not text-align) all these floated child divs with respect to the floated container.

How do I do that ?

At a time, only 1 of these child div is visible on the browser ..User clicks on Prev/Next to view other child divs (kind of like Carousel)

Apparently I am facing issues center aligning if I use float:left for the child div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot align a floated element relative to a parent element.

The `float` CSS property rips an element from its context in the document (similarly to `position:absolute/fixed`). As a result of this, the element cannot be positioned "at the center of the parent".

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for a solution today for my three divs inside a parent container and I came across this old post where a good solution doesn't seem to have been offered.

**My situation:** I have a parent container with width:100% so that it fits the screen. I also set a max-width so that the parent container doesn't grow too large. At the max-width I want the three child divs to display all in one row.

As the page is reduced and the parent container shrinks in width, I want the three child divs to reflow, each child div being pushed under the previous child div until they are all stacked vertically. As this happens I want the child divs to stay center aligned within the parent container.

**The solution** is to *not* use float which "rips an element from its context" as Rob W truly states, but instead use inline-blocks:

```
.parentContainer{
   margin:0 auto; /*keep centered in page*/
   width:100%; /*stretch to page*/
   max-width:800px; /*expand up to 800px*/
   text-align:center; /*keep my children centered*/
}
.childDiv{
   display:inline-block /*treat me as a block that flows like text*/
   width:230px; /*set my size*/
   vertical-align:top; /*keep me aligned at the top of my parent even if my siblings are taller than me*/
}

<div class='parentContainer'>
   <div class='childDiv'>Content 1</div>
   <div class='childDiv'>Content 2</div>
   <div class='childDiv'>Content 3</div>
</div>
```

You can float the parent container, give it absolute positioning, pretty much whatever, and the child divs will keep their same behavior.

**cheers**

Answer (score 1):

If you show only one child `div` at once, probably they don't need to `float`. The best way to center a non-floated block inside of another block is to assign the following style:

```
.child {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will center the `div.child` because both left and right margins will span equally to fit the parent container. Similarly, you can align `div`s to the left and to the right:

```
.left {
    margin-right: auto;
}
.right {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed width for both container and children, then you can use `margin-left` and `margin-right` set to (container div width - contained width width)/2. Of course, if you have paddings and borders, you have to account for them in the formula.